# Smart editor has disappeared from Portal Widgets

Tags: editing, arcgis-portal, widget

I'm just doing a sanity check to see if anyone else is having the same issue: Upon editing a Portal app which used to have the smart editor widget I can no longer select that widget as an option. It's the point of having this particular app, so it's pretty important for its functionality.

I can't post a screen due to security reasons, but the icon for that widget is just simply missing from the list.

Comment: Anything change with the layer settings that the widget is pointing to?

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot. It had somehow been placed in the header without my knowledge. I'm guessing one of my coworkers did that, but I can't back that up.

#facepalm

Basically there can only be one smart editor per app, and somehow one got placed in the header without my knowledge. Once removed from there I could put it where it belongs. The weird thing is that it seems to have been placed there automatically after I tried removing it from the jewelry box tray. So maybe that's a bug, but if so then it's easy to work around if you know what's going on.